# Delete a bunch of attributes on a Backbone Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Whats the best way to delete a bunch of properties on a Backbone model. I think about creating a new model with the properties I wanna keep or delete the unused properties. Any recommendations or better solution for this task?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stay inside the Backbone framework, use model.clear and .set() your new attributes afterwards.

Otherwise you might as well overwrite the model.attributes object directly.

Comment: I think you're better off treating `attributes` as read-only, might work out fine but it is a really bad habit to acquire.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a property, use the model.unset method.